# preg_replace if string doesn't exist, append

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, preg-match

How can i condition a regex to check if string exists in the matched to not to don't duplicate it

here's an example of what i want ( false code )

```
$string = "1234";
$replacement = "/$1(5?)/"; // this should check if "5" is in $string, if not then add it with $1 
preg_replace('/(.*)/', $replacement, $string);
```

what's a good suggestion for `$replacement` ? 
**I only want to use `preg_replace` one line code no other function**

Comment: This smells like homework; why the need of only preg_replace()?

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace('/^([^5]*)$/', '${1}5', '1253'); # => 1253
preg_replace('/^([^5]*)$/', '${1}5', '1234'); # => 12345
```

**NOTE**: used `${1}5` instead of `$15` to distinguish `group 1` from `literal`5`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use strpos()

```
if( strpos($string, $keyword) === false) {
 $string = $string. $keyword;
}
```

Comment: OP explicitly said `I only want to use preg_replace one line code no other function`.